# How to log everything on the screen to a file?

Tags: ruby, logging, rubygems

I use one rb file with `rufus/scheduler` on Windows. The script is executed on a comupter start up and it runs in a cmd window.

How can I log everything that ruby outputs to the screen to a file? I still want to be able to see the output on the screen. So I want the logging on top of current behaviour.

- Windows 7 64 bit
- ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20) [i386-mingw32]

Comment: Do want it to write to both screen and file, or just to the file?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the script to send output to the file instead of the console use [`IO#reopen`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-reopen) to redirect stdout and stderr.

```
def redirect_console(filename)
  $stdout.reopen(filename,'w')
  $stderr.reopen(filename,'w')
end

redirect_console('/my/console/output/file')
```

If you need to direct to one or more output streams, use a proxy object and method_missing to send to them

```
class TeeIO
  def initialize(*streams)
    raise ArgumentError, "Can only tee to IO objects" unless streams.all? { |e| e.is_a? IO }
    @streams = streams
  end

  def method_missing(meth, *args)
    # HACK only returns result of first stream
    @streams.map {|io| io.send(meth, *args) }.first
  end

  def respond_to_missing?(meth, include_all)
    @streams.all? {|io| io.respond_to?(meth, include_all) }
  end
end

def tee_console(filename)
  tee_to = File.open(filename, 'w')
  tee_to.sync = true  # flush after each write
  $stdout = TeeIO.new($stdout, tee_to)
  $stderr = TeeIO.new($stderr, tee_to)
end

tee_console('/my/console/output/file')
```

Comment: I want both. I want to log the console and see the console too. It's just the buffer of the console is not big enough sometimes.

Comment: in unix you could `.reopen('|tee #{filename}"')` I have no idea if windows has a standard tee cmd utility.

Comment: I haven't had time to test it (too busy at work with new release) but I will. Then I comment / accept your answer. Thank you.

Comment: I got this error `c:/edutester/others/functions.rb:212:in 'tee_console': $stdout must have write method, TeeIO given` where the line in error is `$stdout = TeeIO.new($stdout, tee_to)`

Comment: @Radek What version of ruby are you using?

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20) [i386-mingw32]

Comment: @Radek ah, sorry, I misspelled `respond_to_missing?` (missed the `?` suffix).  Fix that and it should work fine.

Comment: Great, I just changed  write mode to append `File.open(filename, 'a')` and I am happy :-) thank you.