# Ruby printing output to file with threads

Tags: ruby

I am writing a Ruby script which loops through some hashes and executes the command in the hash, like so

```
$conf_info = {                                                                                                                                                            
"OpenSSH"   => {                                                                                                                                                      
    "type"  => "static",                                                                                                                                              
    "cmd"   => %q[sshd -T],                                                                                                                                           
    "msg"   => "Testing OpenSSH Configuration",                                                                                                                       
    "res"   => $cmd_results,                                                                                                                                          
    }
}
```

I have multiple of these hashes and I loop through all of them, executing each command.  I am also using threads. The problem is that I can't output to a file.  I have separate threads like this.

```
threads = []                                                                                                                                                      
get_enums($options[:enumerate])                                                                                                                                   
threads << Thread.new {_run_($sys_info  , $options[:system]     , $enum_sys)   }                                                                                  
threads << Thread.new {_run_($net_info  , $options[:network]    , $enum_net)   }
threads.each {|t| t.join}
```

and I output to file like this

```
File.open("test_file", "w") do |file|                                                                                                                                     
    file.puts __start__
end
```

but, the file is only filled with contents like this

```
#<Thread:0x98993fc>
#<Thread:0x9872fcc>
```

and not the actual output of the program.  I would also need the program to output to STDOUT and the file, may someone please tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: But you're printing `__start__`, what do you expect?

Comment: well when I execute __start__ without printing, I get the output that I want.  How do I print the same output to a file?

Answer (score 0):

You can't capture output of `__start__` by assigning it to a variable. You can redirect output instead:

With [TeeIO](https://gist.github.com/Peeja/5489388) (Updated based from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15514745/445221) too):

```
class TeeIO
  def initialize(*ios)
    ios.each{ |e| raise ArgumentError, "Not an IO object: #{e}" if not e.is_a? IO }
    @ios = ios
  end

  def write(data)
    @ios.each{ |io| io.write(data) }
  end

  def close
    @ios.each{ |io| io.close }
  end

  def flush
    @ios.each{ |io| io.flush }
  end

  def method_missing(meth, *args)
    # Return first if it's not an IO or else return self.
    first = @ios.map{ |io| io.send(meth, *args) }.first
    first.is_a? IO ? self : first
  end

  def respond_to_missing?(meth, include_all)
    @ios.all?{ |io| io.respond_to?(meth, include_all) }
  end
end
```

...

```
real_stdout = $stdout
file = File.open("test_file", "w")
$stdout = TeeIO.new(real_stdout, file)

__start__

$stdout = real_stdout
file.close
```

Comment: alright, now I am getting this error "script_name.rb:632:in `popen': undefined method `flush' for #<TeeIO:0x8ede178 @ios=[#<IO:<STDOUT>>, #<File:test_file.txt>]> (NoMethodError)" line 632 is this "result.push(`#{cmd}'.split("\n"))"